# Ошибка в составлении подписи

Tags: python, api, хеширование, hex

Как составить подпись? Предыдущие попытки не дали результата.
Сериализация разработчиков - https://docs.kuna.io/docs/api-data-schema-and-serialization
Библиотек на Python нет.
Вот код, который я составил. Понимания нету. Помогите, разобраться или дать ссылку, где можно понять, как это сделать.
Мой код

```
r = 'https://api.kuna.io/v3/auth/me'
timestamp = str(time.time())
msg = str(r) + str(public_key) + str(timestamp)

kun_signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('ascii'), msg.encode('ascii'), hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'kun-nonce': timestamp,
'kun-apikey': public_key,
'kun-signature': kun_signature}

pool = requests.get(r, headers=headers)
print(pool)
```

Вывод

```
<Response [500]>
```

Какой тип нужно указать? Как сделать такую подпись?

UPD. Поставил `timestamp` в `headers`. Чтобы они совпадали. Все равно, ответ `<Response [500]>`

UPD2. Ответ от поддержки - "Нет возможности изучать код, присланный Вами. Рекомендуем использовать документацию. Спасибо за обращение."

Comment: Как минимум можно попробовать сделать encode для параметров hmac.new: `hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), msg.encode(), hashlib.sha384)`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло) Только теперь я получил `<Response [500]>`

Comment: @Antony зачем для публичного поинта формировать подпись в заголовке? ```url = "https://api.kuna.io:443/v3/timestamp" response = requests.get(url) print(response.text)``` оно и так отвечает ```{"timestamp":1613745044,"timestamp_miliseconds":1613745044880}```

Comment: Опять Вы, Джек) С первого заказа сделаю Вам подгон) Всегда впрягаетесь в мои темы. Спасибо за комментарий, да. Вы правы. Абсолютно незачем. Однако, изменил endpoint `/v3/auth/me'` и по прежнему ответ тот же.

Comment: Самое обидное, что я не знаю, куда двигаться. Ошибка 500 может означать, что угодно.

Comment: эту [обертку](https://github.com/DmytroLitvinov/kuna) не пробовали? (может и устарела c 2018, конечно)... по аналогии вам нужно что-то типа ```hmac.new(secret_key.encode('ascii'), msg.encode('ascii'), hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()```

Comment: Пробовал, конечно. Это первое, что попробовал. По-прежнему `500`

Comment: timestamp пробовали без miliseconds? только ms

Comment: Вы имеете в виду отсюда ms убрать? `timestamp = time.time()`

Comment: да, в документации: nonce указывается в формате Unix Time Stamp в милисекундах (ms), time.time() возвращает флоат с милисекундами

Comment: `key = self.secret_key.encode('ascii')
        msg = msg.encode('ascii')
        return hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()`. Автор той библиотеки не отображает в подписи timestamp вообще.

Comment: Что тогда применить? Какую библиотеку взять?

Comment: время без микросекунд - str(int(time.time()))

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Все тот же 500. Написал в поддержку им. Ответ выложу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант подписи для kuna.io

```
r = 'https://api.kuna.io/v3/auth/me'    
api_path = "/v3/auth/me"
nonce = str(int(time.time()*1000.0))
body = str('')
msg = api_path+nonce+body
print(msg)
kun_signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('ascii'), msg.encode('ascii'), hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'kun-nonce': nonce,
'kun-apikey': public_key,
'kun-signature': kun_signature}

pool = requests.post(r, headers=headers)
print(pool.text)
```

Comment: Работает? Вчера в коментах был этот вариант... что изменилось?

Comment: Да куча косяков было. 1. Неправильно составлен `msg`. В самом `msg` указывается только endpoint. 2. Unix time stamp должен быть в миллисекундах и целочисленным. 3. Запрос не `get`. а `post`. Одной фразой - моя невнимательность.

Comment: Да и результат не обрадовал. Оказывается, что в `v3` отсутствует функционал, который мне был нужен. Придется все переписывать и и переходить на `v2`. Вообщем, как я понял. Запросы приватные от публичных отличаются. И подписи у них разные, что логично.

Comment: После изменения `get` на `post` вышел `response 400`. Это помогло в понимание, что подпись составлена неправильно. Искал фрилансера, который за деньги объяснить эту фишку. Ни одного ответа. 4 биржи, никто не взялся. Пришлось сесть и самого нуля все самому изучать. Несколько людей, включая Вас, указали на важные моменты. За что огромное спасибо! И еще один косяк был в том, что нужно отсылать пустое `body`, даже если запрос не требует этого.